# Replace the '@' sign in formula with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to replace the '@' sign in a formula from 'Inputs' sheet  with this code but it fails:

```
Sub replace()
    Dim fnd As Variant
    Dim rplc As Variant
    fnd = "@"
    rplc = "test"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs").Cells.replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

For example the formula could be `=(100 - (@initialratio*100)) * D10` and I am trying to replace the '@'.

I can replace the '@' manually but I cannot with the vba code. Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: Please go into more detail about what you mean when you say "but it fails".

Comment: sorry, it does not do anything, not replacing anything. If I try to replace 'initialratio' it replaces well but not when I do it with the '@' sign.

Comment: may be better to fix the issue at the source.  how is the formula being placed in the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Replace()
    Dim fnd, rplc
    fnd = "@"
    rplc = "test"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs").Cells.Replace What:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End Sub
```